# How to access google cloud instances from kubernetes containers

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine

I have **k8s** cluster in Google Cloud and **frontend/api** containers there.
In addition to that I have ElasticSearch cluster (**es1,es2**) in Google Cloud but not under **k8s**.

I can access **api** container by name '**api**' from container '**frontend**'.
I can access **es1** from **es2** by name '**es1**'.

What is a right way to access **es** cluster by names like **es1**,**es2** from containers api/frontend ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refer to resources outside of your Kubernetes cluster as if they are inside the cluster, the simplest option is probably to assign each ElasticSearch instance a static IP, and then specify a Kubernetes Service with manual Endpoints:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors

You can add an Endpoint entry for each es instance you have. Now your internal cluster DNS will resolve and load-balance for your es instances as if they were pods in the cluster.

You create endpoints like this (note the lack of selector on the Service):

```
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 1.2.3.4
    ports:
      - port: 9376
---

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9376
```

Now you can access the service using `my-service.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local` as normal.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that

Answer (score 0):

Create the Kubernetes Cluster (GKE) in the same network/subnetwork like your instances, then you can connect the internal Ip´s of your GCE instances from your k8s pods.